# why in make menuconfig some packages are not showing the arrow to choose?

Tags: openwrt

In make menuconfig some packages we can select easily but in the following image,how to enable the virtualization .Telephony,terminal are available we can select.[image: Screenshot of menuconfig]

Comment: You cannot select that item because one or more dependencies have not been selected.  Try reading the `Help` text for that item, which should list its dependencies.

Comment: @sawdust please post your answer as an actual answer.